# Select Previous Date record to be calculated SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
ID     myDate       myTime     Value
1      2014-06-01   00:00:00   100
2      2014-06-01   01:00:00   125
3      2014-06-01   02:00:00   132
4      2014-06-01   03:00:00   139
5      2014-06-01   04:00:00   145
6      2014-06-01   05:00:00   148
FF.
24     2014-06-01   23:00:00   205
25     2014-06-02   00:00:00   209
26     2014-06-02   01:00:00   215
27     2014-06-02   02:00:00   223
FF.
48     2014-06-02   23:00:00   280
49     2014-06-03   00:00:00   290
50     2014-06-03   01:00:00   302
FF.
71     2014-06-03   22:00:00   389
72     2014-06-03   23:00:00   400
73     2014-06-04   00:00:00   405
FF.
```

What I want is the following result:

```
ID     myDate       ResultValue
1      2014-06-01   109
2      2014-06-02   81
3      2014-06-03   115
FF.
```

Where Result Value is Value on the nextdate at 00:00:00 time minus value on the current date at 00:00:00 time. For example, I want to know the Result value on `'2014-06-01'`. So the calculation to find ResultValue is, value on the `next date ('2014-06-02')` at `00:00:00` is `209` minus value on the current date ('2014-06-01') at `00:00:00` is `100`. So the ResultValue is `109`

```
2014-06-02 00:00:00 --> (209) - 2014-06-02 00:00:00 --> (100)
Result: 109
```

Does anyone know how to do this...?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.myDate) AS ID,
  t1.myDate,
  t2.Value - t1.Value AS ResultValue
FROM YOUR_TABLE t1
JOIN YOUR_TABLE t2
  ON t2.myDate = DATEADD(D, 1, t1.myDate)
WHERE t1.myTime = '0:00:00'
AND t2.myTime = '0:00:00'
```

Comment: I run your syntax, but the result value start from 2014-06-02, it should be start on 2014-06-01. The result for 2014-06-01 is 109. But your syntax start from 2014-06-02 and the result is 109.

Comment: That's running very well now. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Take following example script.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(dt DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,res INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @tbl(dt,res)
VALUES
    ('2014-06-01T00:00:00',100),
    ('2014-06-01T01:00:00',125),
    ('2014-06-01T02:00:00',132),
    ('2014-06-02T00:00:00',209),
    ('2014-06-03T00:00:00',290),
    ('2014-06-04T00:00:00',405);

SELECT
    t1.dt,
    t2.res-t1.res AS diff
FROM
    @tbl AS t1
    INNER JOIN @tbl AS t2 ON
        t2.dt=t1.dt+1
WHERE
    (t1.dt - CAST(t1.dt AS DATE))=0
ORDER BY
    t1.dt;
```

You link the data table (t1) to itself (t2) by selecting the next date (t2.dt=t1.dt+1). Selected dates from data table (t1) is restricted to dates that have time part = 00:00:00.000. This is done by casting the date to a DATE type (which has not time part). Subtraction leaves the time part which should equal zero.